# Why do I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when my else should prevent it?

Tags: scala, exception, playframework

I am working on some sort of quiz and have a list of questions and answers, that get transferred to my view class via the controller. People can ask and answer questions on a page, my system then goes and "collects" those to make a quiz out of them.

If you are the first person to start the program / quiz, the question-list is empty. Therefore I want to check for an empty quiz with an if / else clause, the if-case seems to work fine, but the else-case throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and I dont understand why. I would think that the else-part will not be used when the question-list is empty, therefore the exception should not be thrown. Should....

**View class:**

```
@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])

@if(questionList.length == 0){
    No questions yet!
}

else {
<!-- As only the highest ranked question gets put into the List, there is only one entry on first place -->
<b>@questionList.get(0).questionText</b>

    @for(question <- questionList)  {
        @question.questionText - @question.ownerID <br>
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0]
49          <b>"""),_display_(/*27.8*/questionList/*27.20*/.get(0).questionText),format.raw/*27.40*/("""</b>
```

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Just noticed: I can use `@if(questionList > 0)...` and then my code works, but I dont understand why the else does not do the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work - I wonder whether the `==` operator is coming up with a false negative, possibly due to types?  (I.e. `questionList.length` is of a different type to the literal `0`, so they are trivially not equal).  Generally, I prefer using `@if(questionList.isEmpty)` or similar in order to avoid problems like this.

Comment: I tested it with `@if(questionList.isEmpty)`, no change. BUT while trying this I found the solution: There must not be a return / newline between the if-bracket and the else... so thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution and altough it's bad practice to answer your own question, I have searched for several hours for this and maybe my answer helps somebody else:

There must not be a return / newline between the if / else.

Does **NOT** work:

```
@if(questionList.length == 0){
    No questions yet!
}

else { ...
```

**Works:**

```
@if(questionList.length == 0){
    No questions yet!
} else {
```

EDIT: As `@if(questionList.length > 0){` does work also, is stable against accidentically inserting newlines and is a bit easier to read and understand, I will use this instead of the else.

Comment: It is not a bad practice to answer your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

First, does your code compile, as there is no `get` method on List. You can use `list.headOption` instead.

Well, I could use `questionList(0)`

*Another solution.*

```scala
@questionList.headOption.map(q => <b>{q.text}</b>).getOrElse("No questions yet!")
@for(question <- questionList)  {
    @question.text - @question.ownerId <br>
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised, not working for me. What version of Scala and playframework are you using ?

Comment: I am using play framework 2.3.8. It has it's own scala, so I dont know which version the scala is exactly. Can you post your code? Maybe in a pastebin or something like that? Would be interesting to see if this is different in different versions.

Comment: Which version of the play framework are you using in your example?